# Cannot receive push notifications from Quickblox

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, quickblox

I'm trying to set up the messages module in the QuickBlox SDK. I'm able to register in GCM and send the push according to the logs. The problem is that I never get the push notification.

I tried with the default sample keys and with my own. I tried with server key and browser key and nothing.

Let me know what information you need so we can resolve this :(

In the QB console I get this:

```
Notification has been successfully added to queue
```

I tried from the development and production environments and nothing happens.

Comment: I think you can try their Android Chat code sample [here](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample): The Chat sample connects and socializes your users with the chat module. Features include: Peer to Peer Chat; Group chat; Location based chat; `Push notification` for offline users. There should be something you are missing:)

Comment: I noticed that parse and QuickBLox use gcm. Since they are using different client id, I just developed my own gcm modules in php and problem resolved.

Comment: I am facing same issue. How did you solve the issue? I am using FCM